# Spring Data JPA save() throws NPE

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I wrote a web service with spring boot using spring data jpa for persistence.
The webservice has some static objects (in Singleton Bean) that regulary needs to be backed up to my database.

Sometimes! (This sucks...I dont' really know what happens) when I call

`ObjectType updated = myRepository.save(existingObject)`

I get an java.lang.NullPointerException - without usable stacktrace as the method doing this is running via @Scheduled.
I tried debugging and existingObject seems to be absolutely fine. The error only occurs, when existingObject is actually NOT a new object (i.e. when id != 0)

P.S. I am using Spring Boot therefore not really using EntityManager. I only use the @Autowired myRepository.

Comment: I have the suspicion that the @Schedule backup method might actually try to call myRepository.save() while the existingObject might have fields that are null but shouldnt be. Still...this is weird.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing something similar happening. During save, it seems the object is re-fetched from DB (perhaps to see which fields were altered?) but a ManyToOne relationship is not loaded (even though the FetchType is explicitly set to EAGER). 
For some reason, a compareTo is called on the relationship. The related object isn't null, but it only has its ID filled in (presumably because that was available in the object that was fetched from the DB). All other fields are null. 
When the compareTo then does its stuff, a NullPointerException follows.

As to the actual solution, I don't know yet, as I would have expected the FetchType EAGER to make sure the relationship is loaded. Hopefully this helps someone to further find the root cause.

(I would have added this as a comment as it doesn't actually answer the question, but StackOverflow won't let me due to insufficient reputation...)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information. IF that line is where the NullPointerException is occurring, then the only possibilities are that myRepository is null, or existingObject is null. However, it's possible the NullPointerException is happening as a result of something in the save. Wrap the code in a try catch, and log the exception stacktrace to file.

If needed, checkout the logging customization notes here:

- http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot/README.html